# _mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax;)

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I'm new usign MySLQdb for Python. I have this code:

```
for row in csv_reader:
    insert = """INSERT INTO %s
                VALUES (DEFAULT, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s) """
    cursor.execute(insert, (nome_tabela, row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6], row[7], row[8], row[9], row[10], row[11], row[12], row[13], row[14]))
```

But when I execute, I have this following error: `mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''Aquecimento'\n\t\t\t\t\tVALUES (DEFAULT, 'c00010', 'Dorm1', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '3.4' at line 1")`

I'm imagine that the error is conected to the name of the table, but I'm not sure about that.

Comment: the error comes from using `'` instead of backticks for the identifier. not sure how to handle this in python, though.

Comment: Placeholders cannot typically be used for *identifiers* (table and column names and such). If this was a native prepared statement, the database API would reject it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Afaik, `mysql-python` does not handle table names replacement: it blindly adds quotes around all variables and escape data againt SQL injection.

Your best luck is to concatenate the string yourself, but you need to be **extra cautious** about the content of `name_tabela` in this case:

```
insert = (
      "INSERT INTO %s" % name_tabela
      + " VALUES (DEFAULT, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)" 
)
cursor.execute(insert, (row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6], row[7], row[8], row[9], row[10], row[11], row[12], row[13], row[14]))
```

By the way, you can simplfy your `execute` second arg this way:

```
cursor.execute(insert, row[:15])
# or even this if the `row` has exactly 15 values
cursor.execute(insert, row)
```